# Editing question when OPR provides more detail in a comment

Tags: support

I had an edit rejected that I don't understand. See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6764340

All I did was copy the extra information from the OP that was given as a comment, into the original question. I'm not sure I understand what the rejection reasons are trying to say. Is this not a good practice, i.e. to keep the whole question - including new details - in the question area instead of sprinkled throughout later comments?

Comment: This _might have been_ because your prefaced it with `EDIT:`, so it's not super easy to tell that you had copied it _from the comments_. You might want to mention that part next time ("Added more information based on OP in the comments").

Comment: I thought I said that in the comment that explained my edit?

Comment: I essentially added it the way I would have added it if it had been my own question, I.e. show that it is new information.

Comment: So should I edit it again making that clear, or am I now allowed to try to make a rejected edit again?

Comment: First, **don't** use EDIT-markers. We have a perfectly fine edit-history, and it detracts from the question by breaking the flow and coherence. Second, those edits have a summary for a reason: Summarizing and justifying your edit (explicitly mention you moved OPs info from comments on an answer).

Comment: That's why I justified it in the edit summary box. I guess the EDIT was the confusion. So should I edit it again, without the edit marker, or am I not allowed to make a rejected edit again?

Comment: You can try it again, but please properly integrate the edit, and mention *where* you got that info from more explicitly (like "integrating OPs comments on answer"). Also, remove the fluff while you are at it... which the rejecter *should* already have done when he corrected the list formatting.

Comment: I removed some fluff in my previous attempt and corrected the list formatting.

Comment: In general, any edit that adds a big chunk of content is likely to be rejected unless it's made *very* clear where that content came from (such as linking to the OP's comment). That's because people sometimes make things up, or edit their own situation into the question rather than ask their own. A more explicit edit comment would likely have improved your odds.

Answer (score 3):

It's a boundary case IMHO. I would do it only if the question has the potential of becoming a great and useful question.

Usually I only ask the OP to do that themselves, because only then you have a guarantee that you won't make something against the intentions of the OP. You can also advise them to fix the question as a whole including new information.

It's true however, that most of the time they won't do it, and will just put the additional info at the bottom. In the example you've presented I think it wasn't bad (although as I've mentioned - I wouldn't do it). The problem was that it was obviously taken as *changing the original meaning*, as reviewers probably have missed your edit summary.

Side note: as mentioned by [Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator) [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283810/editing-question-when-opr-provides-more-detail-in-a-comment/283811#comment143894_283810), "EDIT" markers are redundant and shouldn't be used. The *whole* post should be fixed, to include new information in a clear and readable way. The question is the most important, not its history.

Comment: I felt that is was missing information from the question as the code would normally be used for another purpose, and it meant my answer was extended a lot and the answer would come before the comment that made it make sense.

Comment: @MoragHughson I understand - as I've said, I don't think it was bad :) However, it was very similar to an incorrect edit so the reviewers probably didn't even read the edit comment.